# Can't seem to be able to bind simple data to ons-list-item in Onsen UI

Tags: angularjs, listview, data-binding, onsen-ui, monaca

I've been fighting with getting an [Onsen UI](http://onsen.io/) based app (running in [Monaca](https://monaca.io/)) to populate the `<ons-list-item>` data and just can't seem to find the right magic syntax.

I started with the ["Sliding Menu" sample template](http://docs.monaca.mobi/en/sampleapp/samples/) and it works just fine, where choosing a menu item navigates to a specific page, e.g.:

announcements.html

```
<ons-navigator var="myNavigator">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left">
        <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="app.slidingMenu.toggleMenu()"><ons-icon icon="bars"></ons-icon></ons-toolbar-button>
      </div>
      <div class="center">Announcements</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <ons-list>
      <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.title}} ({{item.description}})</ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
  </ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
```

If I change the `ng-repeat` attribute value to `items in [1,2,3,4,5]` it renders 5 items in my list just fine.

What I'm struggling with is getting the `items` data to be defined externally.  No matter where I place the `ng-controller="AnnouncementController"` attribute (on the ons-list-item, or any of its parents) I can't seem to get it to be recognized or run.

I've seen many examples setting up a `.controller()` on the ons app, as well as vanilla functions (like below) that just have naming that matches the desired controller.

```
function AnnouncementController($scope, $http){
  $scope.items = [
    {
      title: 'Item 1',
      description: 'Item 1 Description'
    },
    {
      title: 'Item 2',
      description: 'Item 2 Description'
    },
    {
      title: 'Item 3',
      description: 'Item 3 Description'
    }
  ];
}
```

But I can't get any combination to work.  I'm fine if I need to use a controller, or just call an "init/ready" function.  Currently I just want to get anything that works.

Can anyone shed light on where the "magic" binding can/should be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-controller` should be placed inside `ons-list` (or a parent) and `ng-repeat` inside `ons-list-item` as follows:

```
<ons-list ng-controller="MyController">
    <ons-list-item ng-repeat="item in items">
         {{item.title}} - {{item.description}}
    </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

That is enough to make a dynamic list. You can check it here: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/wajagY

If you need more examples, just check MasterDetail template instead of SlidingMenu one ;)

Hope it helps!

**Edit:**

Global controller functions were deprecated in AngularJS. Try to use something like in the Codepen example.

Comment: Thanks, this (in combination with the right syntax for the JS in your codepen link) did the trick. My original controller wasn't defined properly **on** the result of calling `ons.bootstrap()`. I knew it was a silly syntax issue, I just couldn't get the right combination.